# Which LaTeX distribution should I use on OSX?

Tags: mac, distributions

Which LaTeX installation would you recommend using on OSX? Ideally I'd want the installation to contain as many packages as possible as I'll be using my Macbook offline mostly.

Answer (score 21):

Have a look at [MacTeX](http://www.tug.org/mactex/). It should fit your needs as you can choose between different distributions which vary in the amount of installed packages.

Answer (score 16):

I would like to bring to the attention of those of us, who—for whatever reason—like their TeX distribution *minimal*, the [BasicTeX](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/) by Richard Koch. It is based on TeX Live, weighing measly ~90 MB.

*(I realize this answer is pretty much the opposite to what is asked, but given only the title and the tag, I thought it would be good to mention this)*

Comment: +1 for BasicTeX for the initial small download size. I then install whatever packages I usually need via the TeXLive Manager (tlmgr).