# Most reliable LaTeX distributions

Tags: distributions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the advantages of TeX Live over MiKTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20036/what-are-the-advantages-of-tex-live-over-miktex)

I am new to LaTeX and I would like to know what is your opinion about the most reliable LaTeX distribution. I would like to use LaTeX professionally, so I am looking for a robust/stable distribution.

Comment: Miktex and texlive. I use miktex.

Comment: Could you add some information of what platform you use? MikTeX is for Win whereas TeXLive is available for Win/Mac/Linux. Working in Win environment I use MikTeX since years and it is excellent.

Comment: If you are using Windows, see [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1706/how-do-i-get-started-with-latex-on-windows-xp) and [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41808/how-do-i-install-tex-latex-on-windows-7) questions. For Linux, see [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18939/which-latex-to-install-on-linux). For OSX, [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17434/which-latex-distribution-should-i-use-on-osx) will help. As it stands, your question will probably be closed to keep the place tidy, unless you can indicate why the links do not solve your problem.

Comment: In addition to the links @Vivi mentioned see also [What are the advantages of TeX Live over MikTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20036/2693).

Comment: In my view two best authentic resources for newbie on LaTeX distributions is  [Down­load a TEX Sys­tem](http://www.ctan.org/) and [TeX Resources on the Web](http://tug.org/interest.html#texintro). BTW LaTeX itself is reliable, so any one of them is reliable, if you wish a  cross-platform LaTeX distribution then go for [Texlive](http://tug.org/texlive/). if you face any installation problems this Tex.SX forum friends are always there.

Comment: I've used TeX Live since 2009 and I love it!

Comment: I´m working in a Win enviroment. My first pick was actually MikTeX as I read that many are using it. However I experienced problems by downloading it (the download breaks up, I haven´t managed yet to download it) that´s why I started to wonder about the reliability of the application.